# How to configure Jersey JSPTemplatePath without using web.xml

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, ejb, jersey

My web application uses Jersey for serving GET requests. Configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationRESTContext extends PackagesResourceConfig  {

    public ApplicationRESTContext() {
        super("controller.api.", "admin.api");
    }

}
```

Since I'm using Glassfish 3.1 and I want to use only annotations, how is possible to configure Jersey with alternative JSPTemplatePath (com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath) property pointing to /WEB-INF/jsp (I can't put jsps in Web directory because all Jersey is serving all requests /*)?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationRESTContext extends PackagesResourceConfig  {

    public ApplicationRESTContext() {
        super(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
            put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "controller.api;admin.api");
            put(ServletContainer.JSP_TEMPLATES_BASE_PATH, "my-jsp-templates-path");
        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: My jsps are in WEB-INF/jsp and I'm returning Viewable("/test.jsp"), but there is still error. Is this the only way to configure Jersey?